# Problems using cURL in command line, and using it on php

Tags: php, ajax, web-services, curl, command-line-arguments

Well, I'm trying to get some results from a form in a Webpage, I've already logged in, having the PHPSESSID a the responses are OK in the previous steps. If I execute from command line like this:

```
curl "http://domain/"%"27/ajaxform" -H "Cookie: PHPSESSID=l2pgk9rqihvo5n5gf3uq79c5e6" -H "Origin: http://domain" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate" -H "Accept-Language: es,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6,es-419;q=0.4" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.124 Safari/537.36" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8" -H "Accept: */*" -H "Referer: http://domain/inicio" -H "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest" -H "Connection: keep-alive" --data "formName=option1&other=attributes" --compressed > resp.txt
```

I can get the results in the resp.txt file.

But, running it in PHP all I get is http_code 500, I'm using the following code in PHP

```
function check_cdd($optionname, $sessionid){

    $url="http://domain/".urlencode("'")."/ajaxform";
    $cookie="cookie.txt"; 
    $postvars = 'formName='.$optionname.'&other=attributes';
    $ch = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0); 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING , "");
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie); 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postvars); 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, false);  
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);       

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array(
        'Cookie: PHPSESSID='.$sessionid,
        'Origin: http://domain',
        'Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate',
        'Accept-Language: es,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6,es-419;q=0.4',
        'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36',
        'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
        'Accept: */*',
        'Referer: http://domain/inicio',
        'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest',
        'Connection: keep-alive'));


    $result = curl_exec ($ch); 
    $header_size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
    $header = substr($result, 0, $header_size);




    print("<pre>");
    print_r(curl_error($ch));
    print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));

    echo $result;

    print("</pre>");

    curl_close($ch);}.
```

I've tryed differents params and options in PHP side, but always get 500 code in response, don't know what else to try. Thanks in advance for your answers

Answer (score 0):

500 means internal server error...so help me to debug your code, by removing `$postvars` from your curl_setopt() function, it does not exist from your command line, and i suspect that it can be the origin of server error

Comment: $postvars is the query string passed with the - - data  parameters in command line,  the values are the same in both cases